# how do I make spring boot embedded tomcat to return 200 OK for base url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My app is deployed at `http://123.87.65.23:8080`. The context path is `/myapp` configured in `application.properties`. So if I access `http://123.87.65.23:8080`, I get 404. but if I access `http://123.87.65.23:8080/myapp/health`, I get 200 as expected.

Our operation team monitors base url (`http://123.87.65.23:8080`) for 200 OK. 
I have two options:

1. Return 200 OK when I hit `http://123.87.65.23:8080`. No response is required.
2. Or somehow proxy the request `http://123.87.65.23:8080` to `http://123.87.65.23:8080/myapp/health` within my Spring Boot application.

NOTE: I am using embedded tomcat. so the option of changing server.xml is not applicable

I don't how know how to do either options.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `contextPath` attribute in your `.properties` file then Spring does what it's supposed to do, **everything** gets moved there.

If you're packaging the app as a `.war` and running it in an external server then you can set that server up to redirect root requests to whatever URL inside your Spring Boot application.

If you're packaging the app as a runnable `.jar` with an embedded server **and you want to keep the `contextPath` in the `.properties`-level** then

a) you still need some kind of external server that can catch requests to root and redirect to your Spring Boot application

b) you need to set up two distinct `DispatcherServlets` where one's `contextPath` is `/myapp` and the other's is `/` which will redirect to your Spring Boot Application

However, the **easiest** solution would be to remove `contextPath` and just prepend each Controller's `@RequestMapping` with `/myapp`, move all the `management` endpoints to `/myapp` with `management.context-path` and write a single `@Controller` method mapped to `/` that redirects to the health endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In your tomcat container your app should be deployed into a directory named "ROOT", not "myapp", if you wanna use root urls. And I guess your Dispatcherservlet may be configured to process requests to /health, and you need to process just /
Or maybe you've got a Controller, mapped to /health.
Can't tell anything else without code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 200 on `http://123.87.65.23:8080` request, you need an application named `ROOT.war` in your webapps folder.

So `http://123.87.65.23:8080` and `http://123.87.65.23:8080/myapp` are two different applications.

I suggest you two options:

1. Deploy your application as `http://123.87.65.23:8080` (ROOT.war)
2. Use some Proxy Server like nginx or apache. You can configure the proxy server to redirect all ROOT requests to you application

Here are some examples for *nginx*:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://123.87.65.23:8080/myapp/;
}
```

or just return 200:

```
location / {
    return 200;
}
```

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat. so using root.war is not an option for me